# zimbra mail quota view command line

Tags: email-server, zimbra, quota

I am using zimbra 8.5.
When i am trying to view the mail quota of all users from the admin GUI, the whole system hangs and we will have to restart the system to make it work again.

I searched in google but the solutions are little bit confusing for me. Is there any way to view the mail quota of all users in command line. Any command or script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you type zmprov view quota in your favorite search engine the first hit you find is: https://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Getting_All_Users_Quota_Data which to me really does what you need.